# Postgres on kaa cluster nodes dont sync with each other

Tags: iot, kaa

I have setup kaa cluster with two nodes.
The postgres on second node does not sync with the first one, as i add any schema or sdk. Do I need to manually setup replication between postgres.
Or kaa handles this by itself, if it is so then why my second node is not in sync with the first.

> admin-dao.properties
>
> ```
> jdbc_url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.21:5432,192.168.1.22:5432/kaa
> ```
>
> sql-dao.properties
>
> ```
> jdbc_host_port=192.168.1.21:5432,192.168.1.22:5432
> ```

Thanks
Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the replication has to be setup in order for dbs in cluser to sync. And kaa does not handle sync as per their documentation in Architecture Overview
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Architecture-overview/

> SQL database
>
> SQL database instance is used to store tenants, applications, endpoint
>   groups and other metadata that does not grow as the number of
>   endpoints increases.
>
> High availability of a Kaa cluster is achieved by **deploying the SQL
>   database in HA mode**. Kaa officially supports MariaDB and PostgreSQL as
>   the embedded SQL databases at the moment.